# Collectionview's bottom constraints not updated in runtime

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, collectionview

I am using a collectionView with FlowLayout. Please find the following image.

[image]

In the image, the white area is the collectionView. During Runtime the red color view might get hidden based on a condition. So the collectionView will have to move up. That is not an issue. That works as expected. But when the collectionView moves up, the 'All Months' button which is connected to collectionView by vertical spacing constraint of 20 pixels does not move up.

[image]

My requirement is that the 'All Months' button has to be 20 pixels next to the collectionView even if the collectionView changes its y position or height during runtime.

EDIT:
I have moved the contentView of my ScrollView upwards to show you the constraints of 'All Months' and 'Next' buttons. Pl check the following images

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the another constraints for the `ALL months` ?

Comment: will you please show us the constraint added to the all months button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am changing the whole answer after looking and editing your project, here you go with the edited link which i forked from your project:

https://github.com/subhajitregor/AutoLayoutTest

The thing I have Changed:

1. Content View inside your scrollview its height constraints priority is changed to 250(low priority) as it was not getting shorter if your orange view gets hidden.
2. In your `viewWillAppear()` I added `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` and commented out the inner code of `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (you can reopen the code as your needs)

I have checked it and its working as needed. Please do check that project in the link I provided and let me know.

Comment: It is not working. It throws Inequality Constraint Ambiguity Error

Comment: can you provide a demo project with that particular viewcotroller, then I can do it for you. Just upload in git or give me a link to download the demo project, just with that controller in story board.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample project. Please find the same in this url https://github.com/ManojEllappan/AutoLayoutTest.git. My req is, if i select Single Employee in the first page, the employee details page(orange color view) should be shown as in the storyboard. If i select group employee, the orange view should get hidden and the other views should move up accordingly.

Comment: Ok sure. Thank you.

Comment: Please see the edited answer for the link and changes and let me know if you got your desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It works great. Loads of Thanks. Jus a one more doubt, It works great in the portrait orientation.. Now i have turned the simulator to landscape orientation and the vertical spacing between the collectionView and the 'All Months' button did not change. I have updated the screenshot in the question. Is it possible to keep the spacing between the collectionView and the button as '20 px' always.. How can we achieve it?

Comment: As you rotate your device the collectionview's height is constant and the "All Months" button is maintaining its "20px" position to achieve this include
     `override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            collectionViewHeight.constant = 220;
        }
        else {
            collectionViewHeight.constant = 120;
        }
    }`
 in your view controller, I have updated the code in git please refer to it to see how it is working